# AppWidgetTarget doesn't work inside RemoteViewsFactory. How to get around this?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider, android-appwidget-list

There is not enough documentation or blogs around this topic.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Tried this in getView. Works on an imageview that is not part of item of listview.

```
                 val articleImage: AppWidgetTarget = object : AppWidgetTarget(appContext, R.id.article_image, views, appWidgetId) {
                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                        super.onResourceReady(resource, transition)
                    }
                }

                val options = RequestOptions()
                    .override(62, 62)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.news_thumbnail)
                    .error(R.drawable.news_thumbnail)

                Glide
                    .with(appContext)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load("/*URL*/")
                    .apply(options)
                    .into(articleImage)
```

Comment: This has been answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771297/picasso-load-images-to-widget-listview#comment121484613_27851642) It uses Picasso instead of Glide.

Comment: That is a different solution. A good workaround if you are looking to load images in `RemoteViewsFactory`

Answer (score 1):

`AppWidgetTarget` appears to be for an `ImageView` directly in the app widget's layout, as [it uses `updateAppWidget()` to push over the change](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/v4.12.0/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/AppWidgetTarget.java). It does not appear to tie into a `RemoteViewsFactory`, which is how you populate an `AdapterView` inside of an app widget.

Comment: Right. Makes sense looking at code. Is there no straight or out-of-the-box solution to achieve this? 

Comment: @suhas_sm: I did not see a suitable `Target` in that Glide directory, and I am uncertain if it is even possible. I do not know of a "push" mechanism for `RemoteViewsFactory`, such that you could update a row in your list when the image arrived.

Comment: A different solution works. Commented under the question. Thanks, Mark.